# sequelize promise always return false

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I'm creating a react-native app.

The flow works like this, a customer has to input an email and password to signup and the data will be saved in the database. Before the data is saved, I've used the pre-hook beforeValidate to hash the password using bcrypt.

Until here, everything worked fine, but I can't seem to return true when the promise from instanceMethod comparePassword is made.

I have a customer model Customer.js file like below:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('../config/database');

const Customer = db.define('customer', {
    id : {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email : {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password : {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt : {
      type: Sequelize.NOW
    },
    updatedAt : {
      type: Sequelize.NOW
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      afterValidate: (customer) => {
        customer.password = bcrypt.hashSync(customer.password, 10);
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      comparePassword: (candidatePassword) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if(err) {
              return reject(err);
            }
            if(!isMatch) {
              return reject(false);
            }
            resolve(true);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

module.exports = Customer;
```

and a snippet of authRoutes.js file like below:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if ( !email || !password ) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: 'Must provide email and password!'});
  }

  const customer = await Customer.findOne({ where: {email} });

  if(!customer) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: '1. Invalid email or password!'});
  }

  try {
    await customer.comparePassword(password);
    const token = jwt.sign({ email }, 'MY_SECRET_KEY');
    res.send({ email, token });
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: '2. Invalid email or password!'});
  }
});
```

There's no error or anything but it always catches the "2. invalid email or password" error even tho I've input the correct credentials. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `err` in the `catch`?

Comment: and as a side note, `bcrypt` provides a promise api. You don't need to use the `Sync` functions or create that new Promise

Comment: @Matt it returns ` "error": "2. Invalid email or password!"` on postman

Comment: I'm referring to the `err` variable in the catch scope.

Comment: @Matt I'm sorry I'm confused as well. From the code above, I couldn't exactly point out what the error was. Was it reject(err) or reject(false)? But I did a console.log on the err and it said `TypeError: customer.comparePassword is not a function`.

Comment: @SkylarClark i have updated answer with proper try catch and if else condition may be it could help you

Comment: I don't believe you can use `instanceMethods` any more. What version of sequelize are you on? Set `Customer.prototype.comparePassword` to the function instead.

Comment: @Matt My sequelize version is 6.14.6. With my model code, where should I put the `Customer.prototype.comparePassword` ? I can't find the documentation on how to use the newer version. I have put it right above `exports.module = Customer` now I got an error `ReferenceError: comparePassword is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function (comparePassword) to compare password with hashed password Which use bcrypt to compare password.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const customer = await Customer.findOne({ where: { email } });
const comparePassword = (hashedPassword, password) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword);
};
try {
    if (!comparePassword(customer.password, password) {
        return res.status(422).send({ error: '2. Invalid email or password!' });
    }
    else {
        const token = jwt.sign({ email }, 'MY_SECRET_KEY');
        return res.status(200).send({ email, token });

    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).send({ error: 'something bad happened on server' });
}
```

Comment: hey, @Matt I have updated my answer according to the error mentioned by SkylarClark in comment

Comment: Cool. As I mentioned in the other thread, the function can be defined in the sequelilze model via `Customer.prototype.comparePassword` to emulate OPs code.

Comment: and if you make it an `async` function and use `bcrypt.compare()` it won't block the JS event loop

Comment: Thank you @Arya I've used the code and it worked! I'm trying to use the function in my Customer model now to explore more.

Answer (score 0):

`Customer` can be defined as a class in Sequelize 4+. Then instance methods can be added as regular class instance methods.

```
class Customer extends Sequelize.Model {

  static table_schema = {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ...
  }

  static table_options = {
    ...
  }

  static init(sequelize){
    return super.init(this.table_schema, { this.table_options, ...sequelize })
  }

  static associate(models) {
    
  }

  async comparePassword(candidatePassword){
    return bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password)
  }

}

Customer.addHook('afterValidate', async function(customer){
  customer.password = await bcrypt.hash(customer.password, 10);
})
```

Then you should be able to make use of the async `comparePassword` function in your route, similar to [Arya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657999/1318694)

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if ( !email || !password ) {
      return res.status(422).send({error: 'Must provide email and password!'});
    }

    const customer = await Customer.findOne({ where: {email} });
    if (!customer) {
      console.log('Failed login [%s] not found', email)
      return res.status(422).send({error: 'Invalid email or password!'});
    }

    const auth = await customer.comparePassword(password);
    if (!auth) {
      console.log('Failed login [%s] bad password', email)
      return res.status(422).send({error: 'Invalid email or password!'});
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ email }, 'MY_SECRET_KEY');
    res.send({ email, token });
  } 
  catch(err) {
    console.error('Failed to process request', err)
    return res.status(500).send({error: 'Internal Server Error'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning sequelize but the newer version documentations are a bit hard to find. This helped me to use sequelize model in other ways.